# Position: Absolute конфликтует с Flexbox. CSS

Tags: css, css3, scss

У меня есть главный экран, которому я присвоил `position: relative;` и полоска меню, которой присвоил `position: absolute;`.

Хочу сделать, чтобы блок с навигацией был поверх основного, но когда я присваиваю `absolute` блоку с меню, все `margin сверху и снизу` у ссылок навигации пропадают.

Пытался присвоить и `top: 30px;` и `margin` прописать прямо в `html`, не работает.

Вернее, если смотреть из консоли, то видно, что `margin` есть, однако по факту он виден только слева и справа (Использую SCSS).

```css
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav div a {
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="#main">Name</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос, добавив `align-items: center;` в `<nav>`.